# ActiveMQ - number of Message Enqueued and Dequeued, does it cost storage?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have a large number of messages showing as enqueued and dequeued. Also I have purged some messages which are showing in dequeued.

Does it mean the messages are consumed and these numbers are not costing any storage or memory?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Messages Enqueued" are messages that have been added to the queue since the last reset of this stat (likely when the broker was last restarted).

"Messages Dequeued" are messages that have been dispatched to consumers and acknowledged since the last reset of this stat (likely when the broker was last restarted).

These stats aren't particularly relevant for storage utilization. For that you need to look at the number of "pending" messages or the queue "size" or "depth" (different tools may display this information under different headings). These are the messages which are still in the queue. The messages may just be in memory (e.g. if the are non-persistent) or they may be written to disk (e.g. they are persistent or if they've been paged out of memory). The ones that are written to disk will "cost storage" as you put it.